# How to get reshares for link with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

folks,

I shared the link http://example.com/resource/1

Then, I executed FQL-query in Graph Explorer:

```
SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count,
       total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count
FROM link_stat
WHERE url ='http://example.com/resource/1'
```

API returns JSON-data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "share_count": 4,
      "like_count": 0,
      "comment_count": 0,
      "total_count": 4,
      "commentsbox_count": 0,
      "comments_fbid": "10151084809523503",
      "click_count": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

> "share_count": 4

This value is true, posted link have 4 reshares. But «"comment_count": 0» is not true, because link have 3 comments.

1. I posted link.
2. My Friend reshared this link two times.
3. Friend of my friend reshared link from friend's wall.

My link and reshared links have some comments. I know that comments_count shows comments for «comments widget» on this page, but **I need to get all comments or reshares for my link.**

How can I get all the reshares together with friends of friends? (Without using graph.facebook.com/me/home or graph.facebook.com/me/feed)

Also,

```
SELECT likes, tagged_ids, message_tags, description, app_id,
       post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, comments
FROM stream
WHERE filter_key in (
          SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed'
      ) AND is_hidden = 0
```

This query also did not give me anything useful data (**reshares of friends of my friends**).

Thanks.

Comment: What access token are you using when executing the initial FQL query?  The comments on the shared links may be protected by privacy settings.